# Consulta en controlador trae datos diferentes de la DB

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estoy consumiendo un Ajax en JavaScript que yo mismo realice, el problema viene que esta repitiendo los datos en sus tres últimos campos; valide la consulta en la DB y los datos son diferentes contra lo que el Ajax trae, muestro mis funciones:

En asp.net tengo la siguiente función:

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Reportes> GetScrapReport(DateTime fecha, DateTime fechaend)
    {
        try {
            var fechaparametro = new SqlParameter("@fecha", fecha);
            var fechafinparametro = new SqlParameter("@fechafin", fechaend);
            var listareport = _context.Reportes.FromSqlRaw($" SELECT idscrap, fecha, modelo, elemento, nombre, numeroparte, cantidad FROM F_GetScrapReport (@fecha,@fechafin) order by 1 asc", fechaparametro, fechafinparametro);
            return listareport.ToList();
        }
        catch 
        {
            return new List<Reportes>();
        }
    }
```

El modelo `Reportes` contiene la siguiente estructura:

```
public class Reportes
{
    [Key]
    public int Idscrap { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }
    public string elemento { get; set; }
    public string? nombre { get; set; }
    public string? numeroparte { get; set; }
    public int? cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Código de la vista:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="text-center">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Model</th>
                <th scope="col">Element</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Number part</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center" id="tabletimescrap">
            @*Agrego resultado ScrapTime*@
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

La función AJAX JavaScript que arme es la siguiente:

```
        async function GetScraptime()
{
    //var j = 0;
    var fecha = document.getElementById('scraptime');
    var fechafin = document.getElementById('scraptimetwo');
    console.log("Fecha inicial: "+fecha.value);
    console.log("Fecha final: "+fechafin.value);
    if (fecha.value == "" || fechafin.value == "") {
        console.log("Uno de los parametros esta vacio");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "Reportes/GetScrapReport",
                contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'fecha': fecha.value, 'fechaend': fechafin.value },
                async: true,
                success: function (resultado)
                {
                    console.log("Logitud de result: " +resultado.length);
                    $("#tabletimescrap").html('');
                    for await (let item of resultado)
                    {
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("<tr>");
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.idscrap + "</td>");
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.fecha + "</td>");
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.modelo + "</td>");
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.elemento + "</td>");
                        if (item.nombre == null)
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + " " + "</td>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.nombre + "</td>");
                        }
                        if (item.numeroparte == null)
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + " " + "</td>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.numeroparte + "</td>");
                        }
                        if (item.cantidad == null)
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + " " + "</td>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#tabletimescrap").append("<td>" + item.cantidad + "</td>");
                        }
                        $("#tabletimescrap").append("</tr>");
                        //j = j + 1;
                    }
                    console.log(resultado);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

La consulta que estoy realizando la obtengo de una función en SQL que realice, adjunto la función en SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_GetScrapReport (@fecha datetime, @fechafin datetime)
    RETURNS TABLE
        AS RETURN 
        (   SELECT [Scrap].IDScrap
                      ,[fecha]
                      ,M.modelo
                      ,[Scrap].[elemento]
                      ,P.nombre
                      ,P.numeroparte
                      ,Sc.cantidad
                  FROM [dbo].[Scrap] FULL OUTER JOIN Scraparte Sc ON dbo.[Scrap].IDScrap = Sc.IDScrap 
                  JOIN Modelo M ON dbo.[Scrap].IDModelo = M.IDModelo LEFT JOIN Parte P ON Sc.IDParte = P.IDParte
                  WHERE dbo.[Scrap].fecha >= @fecha AND dbo.[Scrap].fecha<= DATEADD(HOUR,23.9999,@fechafin))
```

Y finalmente lo que obtengo en la DB realizando la consulta es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema, es que en la vista, obtengo los siguientes resultados, las columnas **Name**, **Number part** y **Quantity** repiten sus valores, lo cual no hace sentido con lo escrito en la DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado la impresión en consola en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro porque podria estar tomando los mismo valores solo para esas 3 columnas, gracias por leer

Comment: ¿Y si haces un `console.log(result)` los datos son distintos también?

Comment: Hola @masterguru , si también realice la impresión en consola, y dio el mismo resultado, actualizo la pregunta, para añadirlo

Comment: Entonces el problema no está en el ajax en sí, sino en lo que recibe desde asp, y ahí ya no puedo ayudarte pues no se asp.net, lo siento. Suerte!

Comment: Creo que necesitas un distinct en la query y santo remedio.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, ¿pero porque en la DB funciona sin el distinct?

Comment: No será un problema con las fechas. En la db, estás tirando las fechas en un formato,y lo que muestras en la visual es otro formato. El uso de distinct no tiene sentido, cuando la db, te devuelve los datos sin duplicados. El Management Studio que muestras con los resultados es un cliente, igual que cualquier otro, por tanto la salida de la función a los mismos parámetros tiene que ser la misma. Te recomiendo que utilices el `Sql Profiler`, porque el problema puede ser que la entrada no sea la misma. Comprueba `fecha.value` y `fechaFin.value`

Comment: @Javifer2 Hola, de echo para asegurarme del formato uso la sentencia `convert (varchar,REPLACE(@fecha,'"','') , 23)` usando de referencia este  [enlace](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: He actualizado el controlador y la función en SQL para que trabajen con @fecha y @fechanfin de tipo `DateTime`, para validar si mejoraba, pero me he dado cuenta que continuo el problema, los datos de las ultimas 3 columnas no corresponden a los datos  en la DB.

Comment: A mi me suena que ese query es el problema. Esta lleno de joins, lo que puede provocar que se cruzen los campos. Mas que veo que no estas ordenando la salida, entonces vas a ver siempre algo como se le ocurra al programa que uses. Probaste ordenar las salidas? otra cosa, porque usas una funcion para algo que deberia ser una vista o un SP?

Comment: @gbianchi si ordene la consulta, cuando la llamo en el controlador, `...order by 1 asc` y use una función porque se me hizo más simple, pero tienes razón debería ser una vista

Comment: claro, pero ojo, que estas ordenando por un campo que se repite... tu consulta devuelve algo raro, pero el problema tiene que estar en la consulta...

Comment: Ojo que en la query estas buscando data del 05-07-2022 al 06-07-2022 y en la vista del 06-07-2022 al 06-07-2022, intenta buscar las mismas fechas en ambas instancias

Comment: @EduardoValenzuelaGonzalez, hola era de modo demostrativo, pero actualizo el post

Comment: Transforma tu función en async. (async function GetScraptime()
{....) y cambia el while por for await (let item of result) {} dentro cambia todo lo que tenias en el while por ítem en vez de result[j]

Comment: @EduardoValenzuelaGonzalez y cuando la llamo en la vista, ¿es igual? o lleva algun parametro?, porque me responde que esa función no esta definida

Comment: Podrías añadir el código que ejecutas en la vista y el error que te aparece. Aquí tienes un link para que puedas entender las funciones asíncronas en js https://lenguajejs.com/javascript/asincronia/async-await/  Lo más seguro que el error que se repitan los datos sean porque js todo lo ejecuta de forma sincrono, dejo otro link sobre este tema https://www.arquitecturajava.com/javascript-sincrono-o-asincrono/

Comment: @EduardoValenzuelaGonzalez he añadido el código para la vista, un error como tal no aparece, el detalle son las ultimas 3 columnas, que los valores en la vista no representan los valores de la DB es decir mientras que en la DB tengo un 3 en la vista tengo un 1.

Answer (score 1):

El problema era en el **modelo de datos** `Reportes`, donde estoy decorando el campo `Idscrap` con `[Key]` señalando así que es el identificador de la *tabla*, pero en mi consulta no debe haber un identificador, es un `SELECT` con varios `JOIN` ,entonces, el modelo lo decore con `[Keyless]` indicando que el retorno de mi consulta no contendrá un identificador, así me muestra los datos tal cual aparecen en la DB.

```
[Keyless]
    public class Reportes
    {
        public int  Idscrap { get; set; } 
        public DateTime  fecha { get; set; }
        public string modelo { get; set; }
        public string elemento { get; set; }
        public string? nombre { get; set; }
        public string? numeroparte { get; set; }
        public int?  cantidad { get; set; }
    }
```